# AngularJS app URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ngRoute in my AngularJS app to build up different app routes, below is part of my app.js. Now the problem I am facing is that the URL is shown as ( localhost/myapp/index.html#/home ) while my client needs is at localhost/myapp#/home so I was wondering how I can get the index.html out of the equation or at least make it as localhost/myapp/index#/home without the .html? Thanks

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']).
 config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', 
                  { templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', 
                    controller: 'homeController'
                  });
   $routeProvider.when('/about', 
                  {templateUrl: 'templates/aboutus.html', 
                   controller: 'aboutUsController'
                  }); 
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'}); }]);
```

Comment: I think that's a server issue and has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: If you're hosting the site in IIS, you can use the URL rewrite module http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I am testing on a local XAMPP, so what server side issue it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a combination of `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and `<html><head><base href="/myApp">`